# All the third level Submenus in QGIS are gone

Tags: qgis, feature-count

I suddenly am missing all of my third level submenus in QGIS.  I wanted to use count points in polygon which exists on the vector analysis menu- but selecting it shows no other menus or dialog box with the options to select.  It is completely unresponsive.

Same is true for select by location, buffer etc.  Corrupt program?  I am using version 3.8.2

Comment: have you tried to turn it off and on again?

Comment: that tool is probably also available through the processing toolbox